# sqlite3 WAL/SHM files not deleted

Tags: sqlite, wal

I have the following code

```
int main(){
sqlite3 *db;
int     rc;
char filename[512];
char query[512];
char trace_string[512];
sqlite3_stmt *Stmt;
const char *zLeftover;

strcpy(filename,"/data/xcd/textdatabase/2015274/2015274_mos.sqlite");
strcpy(query,"ATTACH '/data/xcd/textdatabase/2015273/2015273_mos.sqlite' as db1");

rc = sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db,SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    sprintf(trace_string,"open_database: failed to open %s, rc=%d\n", filename, rc);
    fprintf(stdout,trace_string);
    return 0;
}
else {
    sprintf(trace_string,"open_database: %s opened rc=%d\n", filename, rc);
    fprintf(stdout,trace_string);
}

rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, query, -1, &Stmt, &zLeftover);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    sprintf(trace_string,"test: sqlite3_prepare, command=%s, rc=%d\n", query, rc);
    fprintf(stdout,trace_string);
    return rc;
}

rc = sqlite3_step(Stmt);
if ((rc != SQLITE_OK) && (rc != SQLITE_DONE) && (rc != SQLITE_ROW)) {
    sprintf(trace_string,"test: sqlite3_step, command=%s, rc=%d\n", query, rc);
    fprintf(stdout,trace_string);
    return rc;
}

rc = sqlite3_finalize(Stmt);

sprintf(trace_string,"test: sqlite3_finalize, command=%s, rc=%d\n", query, rc);
fprintf(stdout,trace_string);

rc=sqlite3_close(db);
sprintf(trace_string,"close_database: rc=%d\n", rc);
fprintf(stdout,trace_string);
return (rc);
```

}

The databases I'm working with are write ahead logging (WAL) databases.  According to the SQLite documentation, the shm and wal files are supposed to be deleted upon completion of the program. However, these files are still there after execution of this program. The documentation says the files might still be there if the program does not complete cleanly, but I'm just not seeing that. Any insight? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `-shm` and `-wal` files are deleted after a [checkpoint](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt).
This cannot be done on a read-only database.

Comment: For a read-only database, I wish it wouldn't create this sort of thing at all... :/

Comment: Why are you trying to use a [read-only WAL](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#readonly) anyway?

Comment: Because the data is evidence which is not supposed to be modified while we're reading it.

Comment: Make a copy, and open that.

Comment: That's what we're doing, so now I'm also trying to stop it also creating additional files in tmp.